# If conditions as inline style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to add an inline-style to an element with HAML.
Somwhow, the style does not show up inside the tag - any idea whats wrong with it?

```
%span.proceed-to-checkout.four.columns.offset-by-six{ :style => (@order.empty? ? 'display: none;' : 'display: inline;)'}
```

Comment: Assuming the `)'` at the end is just a typo and should be `')`, this appears to work for me. Can you provide an example of the HTML you are seeing and what you want to get?

Answer (score 3):

You are not correctly closing last parenthesis. I think you can even remove them. Try:

```
{ :style => @order.empty? ? 'display: none;' : 'display: inline;' }
```